# Get full file path on shared network drive when mounted volume includes subfolder

Tags: macos, network, finder, smb

We have a shared samba file server with paths like

```
smb://server/folder1/folder2/file.txt
```

It is common for people to "connect to server" directly to `smb://server/folder1/folder2`

This mounts a volume called "folder2".  We need the full path of the path, to share it e.g. `smb://server/folder1/folder2/file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

```
mount
```

this command would show you the SMB URL, e.g
//server/folder1/folder2/